# Spark: is there a way to print out classpath of both spark-shell and spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I can run a spark job successfully in the spark-shell but when its packages and run through spark-submit Im getting a NoSuchMethodError.

This indicates to me some sort of mismatch of classpaths. Is there a way I can compare the two classpaths? Some sort of logging statement?

Thanks!

```
15/05/28 12:46:46 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at com.ldamodel.LdaModel$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(LdaModel.scala:22)
    at com.ldamodel.LdaModel$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(LdaModel.scala:22)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at com.ldamodel.LdaModel$$anonfun$5.apply(LdaModel.scala:22)
    at com.ldamodel.LdaModel$$anonfun$5.apply(LdaModel.scala:22)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: This can also be a result of a version mismatch between the spark and scala versions used for building the .jar file and the version on the cluster that you might be running the jars on. With spark-shell, this problem is nonexistent.

Comment: @catrapture Were you able to solve this specific problem? I am having the same issue as well in the same context (spark-submit with fat jar), and have not been able to resolve so far. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, @Amir. I had a similar issue related to classpath where I was using spark 2.1 to run code compiled with spark 1.6 version. apparently, 1.6 uses scala 2.10.. while spark 2.1 uses scala 2.11...

Answer (score 40):

I think [this should work](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/):

```
    import java.lang.ClassLoader
    val cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader
    cl.asInstanceOf[java.net.URLClassLoader].getURLs.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 26):

Without modifying the code:

```
SPARK_PRINT_LAUNCH_COMMAND=true /usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-shell
```

Also works with `spark-submit`.

Answer (score 13):

This should do the trick without requiring any code changes:

```
--conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-verbose:class'
--conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-verbose:class'
```

Comment: this is way too verbose for me, showing stuff like `[Loaded java.awt.event.ActionListener from /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-oracle-1.8.0_152.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar]`

Answer (score -4):

```
/opt/spark/bin/compute-classpath.sh
```

Comment: What system are you on?