# Why does the classpath used by spark-submit unexpectedly have jars from under the python installation?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, classpath

I have a jar file that contains some Scala (and Java) code that I run using the following spark-submit command:

```
spark-submit 
--verbose
--class mycompany.MyClass 
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dconfig.resource=dev-test.conf 
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dconfig.resource=dev-test.conf -verbose:class" 
--conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-verbose:class' 
--master yarn 
--driver-library-path /usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native/ 
--jars /home/hadoop/mydir/spark-utils-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,/usr/lib/phoenix/phoenix-client-hbase-2.4-5.1.2.jar,/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/hadoop-lzo.jar,/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-compress-1.18.jar,/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-aws-3.2.1-amzn-5.jar,/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.31.jar 
--files /home/hadoop/mydir/dev-test.conf 
--queue default /home/hadoop/mydir/spark-utils-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
<<args to MyClass>>
```

When I run it, I get an error message - “IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider not found”, which is caused by a version mismatch.  It seems `IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider` was added to `hadoop-aws` in version 3.3.0 and we want to use 3.2.1.  I've gone through our maven dependencies and feel confident that we are not trying to use 3.3.x anywhere.

I've attempted to debug the problem by adding some "verbose" arguments to the command, and I've also added some debug code to `MyClass` to print out the classpath in effect, following the instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512598/spark-is-there-a-way-to-print-out-classpath-of-both-spark-shell-and-spark).

When I look at the output, the classpath in effect when we run the spark-submit command includes a lot of jars included with Python, including `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/jars/hadoop-client-api-3.3.1.jar`.  Thus far, I've been unable to figure out why we are loading jars from `/usr/local/lib/python3.7`.

Can anybody explain to me where those dependencies are coming from, or suggest a way that I could debug where those dependencies come from?  I thought the python might be a result of some environment variable setting, but if so, it doesn't seem to be set at the top level:

```
set|grep -i python
```

doesn't return anything.